# Load formulas and values to SpreadsheetGear UI

Tags: wpf, datasource, spreadsheetgear

Is there a way to load formulas, values and maybe also cell formattings from a given datasource file, like an XML file or .xlsx file directly to SpreadsheetGear WorkbookView UI (WPF)?

For example, I would create an .xlsx file which acts as a data source and where cell A1 holds for example a formula "=A1+B1".
Then, on initializing the UI I would read the file and that formula would be inserted straight onto the UI, without a need to write IRange.Formula="A1+B1" in a code-behind class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear supports reading/writing/displaying workbooks using either of Excel's two major file formats--Excel 97-2003 (*.xls) and Open XML (*.xlsx or *.xlsm).  See the SpreadsheetGear.[FileFormat](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.html) enum for more information.

Use the Factory.[GetWorkbook](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.Factory~GetWorkbook%28String%29.html)() method to open a workbook from disk, then set your WorkbookView's [ActiveWorkbook](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.WPF~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Controls.WorkbookView~ActiveWorkbook.html) property to the [IWorkbook](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook.html) object returned from `Factory.GetWorkbook(...)` to display it.  There is also a WorkbookView.[ActiveWorksheet](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.WPF~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Controls.WorkbookView~ActiveWorksheet.html) if you need to specify a particular worksheet within the workbook to display.  Example:

```
IWorkbook workbook = Factory.GetWorkbook(@"c:\path\to\workbook.xlsx");
worbookView.ActiveWorkbook = workbook;
```